# Hosting Nuxt 3 in Netify : Issue with hnswlib

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vector-database

im facing issue when trying to run stored vector but im getting error.not sure how to solve the issue

the error :"Error: Could not import hnswlib-node. Please install hnswlib-node as a dependency with, e.g. `npm install -S hnswlib-node`.\n\nError: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found (required by /var/task/.netlify/functions-internal/server/node_modules/hnswlib-node/build/Release/addon.node)"

I have already installed `npm install -S hnswlib-node` but still having same issue

Mainly the Hnslib is used for below

`vectorStore = await HNSWLib.load(VECTOR_STORE_PATH, Embeddings);`

im open to use monogodb or superbase for embedding but not sure how to achive it

if anyone can guide me to solve this issue would be great, thank you